# General fiber and the symmetric product of an ample hypersurface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, schemes, symmetric-spaces, chow-groups

Let $Sym^m(X)$ be the $m$th symmetric product of a smooth projective  variety $X$, $n=\dim(X)$, $Y_1$ an ample  hypersurface  of $X$, and $CH_0(X)_{hom}$ the  Chow  groups  of $0$-cycles of degree $0$.

I read the following in the proof  of a proposition in Voisin's book "Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry II", page 286:

We thus conclude that a general fiber  of $\sigma_m^{P_0}:Sym^m(X)\rightarrow CH_0(X)_{hom}$ intersect $Sym^m(Y_1)$ for sufficiently large $m$ and $n\geq 2$.

This means that
\begin{equation*}
     \sigma^{P_0}_m:Sym^m(X)\rightarrow CH_0(X)_{hom}
 \end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
    \sigma^{P_0}_m\arrowvert_{Sym^m(Y_1)}:Sym^m(Y_1)\rightarrow CH_0(X)_{hom}  
  \end{equation*}
have the same image for a sufficiently large $m$.

But  I can not see how  to get  this  implication, so I would be grateful if  someone can give any advise about  it. Thank you!

Comment: I suppose you are asking for an explanation of "This means that..."? You must prove that a general element  $\mathfrak{z}\in\operatorname{Sym}^m(X) $ is linearly equivalent to an element of $\operatorname{Sym}^m(Y_1) $. This is exactly saying that the fiber of $\sigma ^{P_0}_{m}$ containing $\mathfrak{z}$ contains an element of $\operatorname{Sym}^m(Y_1) $, i.e. intersects this subspace.

Comment: P.S: This is the second question you ask about Voisin's book, and both had a very simple answer. I think you should try to think more before posting such questions here.